# grails - how to save ArrayList in db

Tags: grails, groovy, dns, has-many, hbase

I use grails-1.3.2 and hbase plugin.
I have some difficulty in creating one-to-Many association with 
hbase (i can work with hibernate), so
i decided to try create one-to-Many association with using ArrayList.

Here are my domain classes and controllers:

```
class Contacts {

    String con   

    static constraints = {}
}

class ContactsController {

    def create = {
        def contact = new Contacts()
        contact.con = params.con
        contact.save(flush:true)
    }
}

class User {

    String firstname
    String lastname

    // static hasMany = [contact: Contacts]

    static ArrayList<Contacts> contact    

    static constraints = {}
}

class UserController{

    def create = {
        def user = new User()

        user.properties = params
        user.save(flush: true)
    }

    def addContact = {
        def user = User.get(params.userID)
        def contact = Contacts.get(params.contactID)

        user.contact.add(contact)
        user.save(flush:true)
    }
}
```

In `addContact` action `user.contact = null`, so it can not work.
In user does nor appear `contact` field.

Can someone help me understand what i have to do for saving `ArrayList` in `db`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about hbase, but the static `contact` property of the `User` class looks very suspicious. The fact that this property is static, implies that every user has the same contact list, which seems unlikely to be the desired behaviour.

In a standard GORM domain model - assuming you want each `User` to have their own contact list - this would be defined

```
class User {    
    String firstname
    String lastname

    static hasMany = [contact: Contacts]
}
```

Although it looks like we're also defining a static property here, it's actually just the definition of how the `Contact` and `User` classes are related (AKA mapping) that is static. The `contact` property that is dynamically added to the `User` class is non-static.

### Aside

I recommend renaming the `Contacts` class to `Contact` and  the `contact` property to `contacts`. The GORM mapping would then look like this:

```
class User {    
    String firstname
    String lastname

    static hasMany = [contacts: Contact]
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply..i know how to create one-to-Many association with hasMany, but i can not run it for hbase.That's why i am looking for alternative ways..